# Create OGG Files from Java

Tags: java, video, ogg

I want to create OGG format for Video.  I am looking for a Java library to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information please?

Comment: Define "OGG format for video."  OGG is a container format and supports video just fine.  Are you looking to create a similar container format for your own videos?  Are you looking for a library (for Java, I take it) which will write to OGG containers?  Or simply read from them?  etc.

Comment: Yup i am looking for Library for JAVA .. can you give me the link? or provide the help

Comment: What inputs will you already have to create the video from?  If it's the name of an existing video file you wish to repackage, that's a very difference question to if you're receiving a stream of raw video bytes and will have to apply a codec yourself, etc.  Also, why Ogg?  Playing devil's advocate, what requirements prevent you from using e.g. WMF or similar instead?

Answer (score 1):

Xiph provides an open source java library that has a Vorbis Encoder. It can convert a WAV file to Ogg file.

Please have a look at http://xiph.org/downloads/ (search for vorbis-java)

Hope it helps.